# Is there a way to sort values in multimap which have equal values?

Tags: c++

This function only removes repeated values if they are neighbour. How can it remove repeated values from all values and not just the neighbour value?

```
 multimap<string, DictionaryItem> getDistinctI(multimap<string, DictionaryItem> distinct) {
      if (distinct.size() > 1) {
            auto it = begin(distinct);
            auto previousIt = it;
            ++it;
            while (it != end(distinct)) {
                if (previousIt->second.getDefinition() == it->second.getDefinition()
                    && previousIt->second.getPartOfSpeech() == it->second.getPartOfSpeech()) {
                    it = distinct.erase(it);
                }
                else {
                    previousIt = it;
                       ++it;
                }
           }
       }
        return distinct;
    }
```

Comment: Aren't they sorted "just right" at start? Perhaps just hand them over to a `*map`?

Comment: The `std::multimap` is already sorted so all duplicates are next to one another.